# How to pass the index value of a ngFor loop into the component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have a ngFor loop in my code.
and inside this ngFor loop I have a div, on clicking this div I want to pass the index value to the type script file.

I am new to Anglular 2 any help will be appreciated.

Eg:

```
`<div *ngFor="let y of characters;let i = index">
    <div (click)="passIndexValue()">
    </div>
<div>`
```

Comment: why are you not using "i"? I mean you can pass "i" to passIndexValue() function right?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let y of characters;let i = index">
    <div (click)="passIndexValue(i)">
    </div>
<div>`


passIndexValue(index){
   console.log(index);//clicked index
}
```

You could also pass the value to the component like so (assuming below use of @Input)

```
<div *ngFor="let y of characters;let i = index">
    <childComponent [index]="i">
    </childComponent>
<div>`
```

And then pick up the value on the component object:

```
@Input() index: number;
```

And use it directly in the template of the child component like so:

```
<div id="mydivinstance_{{index}}"></div>
```

Thereby allowing a component to have a unique ID based on the *ngFor loop.

Comment: This is not working getting 0 always

Comment: @user1703145 can you please post your code so I can fix it for you